# Lets merge [tag:street-fighter-4] and [tag:super-street-fighter-4] to [tag:street-fighter-4-series]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merging

Lets merge [street-fighter-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-4) and [super-street-fighter-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-street-fighter-4) to [street-fighter-4-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-4-series).

They have each about 25 questions of which most overlap anyways. Some have both tags, others only one. After looking through most of them I think that at least 60% of the questions can be asked for all Street Fighter 4 branches.

Furthermore there are new versions like Super Street Fighter IV Arcade Edition and Super Street Fighter Arcade Edition 2012, which should have their own tag. But even I do not bother with creating the according tags and ask them for [super-street-fighter-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-street-fighter-4).

The game engine is the same in all of them. The new ones have some balances, a bunch of new moves and characters.

Comment: Remember: If you downvote, please consider explaining why.

Comment: I would be hesitant to combine these if 40% of the questions do not pertain to both. We have tags for games with only a couple questions. If there are 20 questions that pertain to one of these games specifically, it should probably have its own tag, in my opinion.

Comment: Could we still create the street-fighter-4-series tag, because once we really have more similar tags (super-street-fighter-4-ae and super-street-fighter-4-ae-2012) it gets really messy asking something very general, that applies to all of them.

Comment: @RavenDreamer What's the approach to bump this discussion? The more releases that get added (Ultra coming soon) the more obnoxious and useless our tagging system becomes. The newest game is even going to let you pick which version of characters you want to use, convoluting our current system even further.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with this.  Street fighter 4 and Super Street fighter 4 (and AE) are different.  yes the game engine is the same, but the balancing has drastically changed the matchups and tiering of various characters.

For example, Fei Long in SF4 was considered a middle tier character.  He got a bump in SSF4 that made him near top tier. He's considered among the best in SSF4AE.

Comment: Can you link to a few questions that would significantly be affected by the proposed merge?

Comment: @Decency your [own question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30440/i-liked-bryan-fury-in-tekken-who-suits-my-playstyle-in-ssf4-ae) refers to only AE since guy and cody aren't in regular SF4 :P

Comment: True, but my question also applies to Super and v2012. I guess the point of this merge to me is that when someone says "SF4" they almost always mean the latest version of it, not the original (Vanilla). Few are going to indicate "Super Street Fighter 4 Arcade Edition Version 2012" as the game they play, and if you look through the questions tagged SF4 almost all of them are relevant to Super/AE/2012 too.

Comment: My suggestion would be to create an SF4-Vanilla tag for those that have specific questions about it (if there even are any), thus opening the far more common Street-Fighter-4 tag for the version of the game that people are actually playing.

Comment: @Decency I'd rather we had a non-automatically-merged street-fighter-4-series tag that we can use for questions that apply to all games, plus game-specific tags for game-specific inquiries like balance discussion (even if there are very few of those). I don't like the idea of a "-vanilla" tag as it would be a first on the site.

Comment: @badp Works for me. The vast majority of questions would simply fall under the sf4-series tag.

Answer (score 2):

The vast majority of questions I've seen/answered on these tags apply to both games. We don't have separate tags for each version of StarCraft or LoL that comes out, even though the gameplay balance can shift dramatically between them, and so having different tags for various SF4 patches, a game which has a notably smaller player base, is overkill.

The games:

- Street Fighter 4 ("Vanilla")
- Super Street Fighter 4
- Super Street Fighter 4 Arcade Edition
- Super Street Fighter 4 AE v2012
- Super Street Fighter 4 AE v2013
- Ultra Street Fighter 4 (To come)

If you say you play SF4, pretty much everyone is going to assume you mean the newest version.

---

So, this came up again as an obvious issue. Can we do this yet, or maybe have some dissenting opinions by people who play the game? I don't even think it's possible to play anything but the latest version on PC with GFWL or Steam...

Answer (score 1):

Here's my counterproposal:

- Create the [street-fighter-4-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-4-series) tag. Manually apply it to questions that do not apply to any SF4 game in particular.
- Leave the rest of the questions tagged with their game name.